# Bad research experience and PhD application

Tags: graduate-admissions, statement-of-purpose

I am currently applying to PhD programs. I have worked as a research assistant for about two years now. Most of the time, I have been taking and studying for some M.Sc level courses. In terms of research (I was free to do research for about one year), I have accomplished nothing. There are two reasons: 1) the subject that I was studying (in mathematics) requires a lot of background knowledge, and 2) my advisor does not really know the subject. So, he did not provide me with any useful suggestions or feedback. Furthermore, I have had bad experiences with him. Now, I am reluctant to list that research experience (to be honest, I was working completely independently). So, what will happen if I do not list this experience in my PhD application? I am willing to write about what I was doing in that period in terms of research. However, I do not want to request a recommendation letter from my advisor because 1) He does not really know what I was doing, and 2) I am afraid he will write a negative letter

Answer (score 1):

Others might disagree, but I would list the research project, perhaps not in great detail. The SoP, remember, is forward looking, not backward. Mention the past only so much as that supports your future academic and career plans. The CV should be used to give a picture of the past, not the SoP.

So, don't use the SoP to detail what you have done in the past.

But there is no shame, in mathematics, for work that proves unfruitful. Some problems are just hard. Virtually everyone in my generation spent at least a bit of time thinking about and "working on" the *Four Color Problem*. But none of us was able to prove the theorem. It was still a valuable exercise in developing our mathematical insight. Often what doesn't work gives you a lot of insight, just as learning what does.

A bad relationship with an advisor is a more serious issue, I think. You will probably need to work out a solution to that. But you may be assuming things incorrectly about his opinion of you. Perhaps you can find a way to explore that directly. Otherwise you will need to find another source of good letters.

Comment: Thank you. Suppose I can't work out a solution with my advisor, would it be possible to list that experience without a letter from him? Actually, during that period, even if I was employed as a research assistant, I virtually worked independently.

Comment: I would probably put a line in the cv giving some appropriate name to the project. "Research Experience: Mumble foo mumble. Dr. Bar, PI." If you are asked about it, explain further. But if you are asked it is because you have made some initial cut.